# Sonatype Nexus - Docker images to be seen by one user

Tags: docker, registry, nexus, docker-registry, sonatype

I'm currently using nexus 3.1 as a private docker registry.
We have clients that are interested in storing their docker images in the registry, 
They require however the ability for their images to be seen only by their specific user, meaning, no other user should be able to see that their docker images exist.
Is there a proper way to make this happen ?

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways how to achieve this:

- set up a separate docker registry with access just for that specific user
- use [content selectors](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/configuration/repository-management#RepositoryManagement-ContentSelectors) to restrict all but the specific user from accessing some of the images